# titletop error I can't write on thesis.pdf

Tags: titles, front-matter, titleps

I am using a template given to me by department. The first few lines are as follows

```
\documentclass[oneside,mtp]{universityg}

% The iitkgp.cls class is for producing theses and dissertations
% in the CSE Department of universityG.  You can supply
% the following optional arguments in the square brackets to
% specify the thesis type:
%
%   senior  : Produces the senior thesis preliminary pages (default)
%   phd     : Produces the PhD dissertation preliminary pages
%
% FOR ALL DEPARTMENTS, open universityg.cls file, go to the "Certificate Page" section
% of the main code and make appropriate changes.
%
% FOR DEPARTMENTS other than CSE open the university.cls file, go to the "Title Page" section
% of the main code and make appropriate changes.
%
% The default format is appropriate for printing, with blank pages
% inserted after the preliminary pages in twoside mode so you can
% send it directly to a two-sided printer. Howev  er, for ETD
% submission the blank pages need to be removed from the final output.
% The following option does this for you:
%
%   etd     : Produces a copy with no blank pages in the preliminary section.
%             Remove this option to produce a version with blank pages inserted
%             for easy double sided printing.
%
% The rest of the class options are the same as the regular book class.
% A few to remember:
%
%   oneside : Produces single sided print layout (recommended for theses less than 50 pages)
%   twoside : Produces single sided print layout (the default if you remove oneside)
%
% The BYUPhys class provides the following macros:
%
%   \makepreliminarypages : Makes the preliminary pages
%   \clearemptydoublepage : same as \cleardoublepage but doesn't put page numbers
%                           on blank intervening pages
%   \singlespace          : switch to single spaced lines
%   \doublespace          : switch to double spaced lines
%
% --------------------------- Load Packages ---------------------------------

% The graphicx package allows the inclusion of figures.  Plain LaTeX and
% pdfLaTeX handle graphics differently. The following code checks which one
% you are compiling with, and switches the graphicx package options accordingly.





%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{changepage,ifthen}
%\textwidth 6.5in
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
%\textheight 10in
%\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{2}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{arydshln}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,verbatim,eufrak}
%\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

%\usepackage{natbib,stfloats}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\algtext*{EndIf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
%\usepackage[lined,algonl,algochapter,algoruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\newcommand {\g}[1]{\textcolor[gray]{0.6} {#1}}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{TODO: #1}\\}
\newcommand{\done}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{Tried to address. #1}\\}

% these are for the algorithms style file, for writing algorithms
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
%\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\begin{small}/* #1 */\end{small}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{/* #1 */}

% The fancyhdr package allows you to easily customize the page header.
% The settings below produce a nice, well separated header.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ \ #1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \ #1}}

% The caption package allows us to change the formatting of figure captions.
% The commands here change to the suggested caption format: single spaced and a bold tag
% Change the \DeclareCaptionFormat line below to make the captions fully bold
\usepackage{caption}
%\DeclareCaptionFormat{suggested}{\singlespace#1#2 #3\par\doublespace}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{suggested}{\singlespace \textbf{#1}\textbf{#2}#3 \doublespace}
\captionsetup{format=suggested}

%To instruct Latex to try to fit each paragraph into 1 less line
%\let\markeverypar\everypar
%\newtoks\everypar
%\everypar\markeverypar
%\markeverypar{\the\everypar\looseness=-1\relax}

%\newcommand{\captionfonts}{\small}

% The cite package cleans up the way citations are handled.  For example, it
% changes the citation [1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,11] into [1-3,6-11].  If your advisor
% wants superscript citations, use the overcite package instead of the cite package.
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage[tone]{tipa}

% The makeidx package makes your index for you.  To make an index entry,
% go to the place in the book that should be referenced and type
%  \index{key}
% An index entry labeled "key" (or whatever you type) will then
% be included and point to the correct page.
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{rm}

% If you have a lot of equations, you might be interested in the amstex package.
% It defines a number of environments and macros that are helpful for mathematics.
% We don't do much math in this example, so we haven't used amstex here.
%
% To include a link in your pdf use \href{URL}{Text to be displayed}.  If your
% display text is the URL, you probably should use the \url{} command discussed
% above.
%
% To add a bookmark in the pdf you can use \pdfbookmark.  You can look up its usage
% in the hyperref package documentation
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,pdfpagelabels=true,plainpages=false,colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}

% ---------------- Fill in these fields for the preliminary pages -------------------
%
% For Senior and honors this is the year and month that you submit the thesis
% For Masters and PhD, this is your graduation date

\newcommand{\bigsize}{\fontsize{14pt}{20pt}\selectfont}

\Year{2020}
\Month{April}
\Author{AAAAAA}
\degree{Master of Technology}
% If you have a long title, split it between two lines. The \TitleBottom field defines the second line
% A two line title should be an "inverted pyramid" with the top line longer than the bottom.
\TitleTop{{\bigsize \bf Anomaly Detection in Cloud Computing}}
%\TitleBottom{{\bigsize \bf  MEMORY SYSTEMS }}
%\TitleBottomagain{{\bigsize \bf MEMORY SYSTEMS}}
% Your research advisors
\AdvisorA{{Dr AAAA AAAA}}
```

the above code is in thesis.tex file 
I compile this in miktex and I am getting following error in thesis.out file

```
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{bm:Title.0}{Title Page}{}% 1
```

the logs show following

```
I can't write on file `thesis.pdf'. \BOOKMARK [0][-]{bm:Title.0}{Title Page}{}
```

what could be the possible cause of this error?

Also I am getting warning as below

```
fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015(fixltx2e) All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
```

why is this warning coming?

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: As to the warning, it comes because your preamble loads the obsolete `fixltx2e`. Remove it.

Comment: I use TexStudio on Miktex , TexStudio uses its internal pdf viewer.

Comment: this is the full template if you want to have a look https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template